# How can I "un-inherit" a Maven dependency?

Tags: maven, dependency-management

I have a large multi-module project. 99% of the modules have a dependency on a certain third-party library (let's call it A), so the dependency on A is recorded in the project parent POM & thus inherited by all of the modules. In these 99% of cases A is provided as part of the runtime environment & thus the dependency is accordingly marked as provided.

I've run across a situation today where one of the child modules (actually a grandchild, if that matters) **must not** have a dependency on A. How can I remove A from the dependency list of this module?

I've tried `combine.self="override"` but that construct apparently isn't allowed in the `<dependencies>` element.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do what you are asking. I think you will have to stop inheriting A (remove it from the parent) and start declaring it specifically in all child modules.

Comment: @BenjaminLinus, I figured as much. That's a terrible "fix" that's not going to happen though: I'm not about to individually declare dependencies in 300+ modules to work around this one corner case.

Comment: I hear ya, I wouldn't want to do that either. Another possibility would be to remove the "<parent>" declaration from 1% child modules, then specifically declare all the stuff that would have been inherited from the parent. Still a terrible fix but maybe not so terrible as touching 300+ modules. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dependencyManagement` and add dependency exclusion of the artifact that you don't need.

This works as a charm on excluding `commons-logging` from my spring dependencies:

```
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>

    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: I'm not asking how to exclude a transitive dependency: I'm asking how to prevent a single descendant from inheriting a dependency that is directly declared by an ancestor.